# How to install libmysqld-dev on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, ffmpeg, libraries

I have looked through many forums but can't find how to install libvdpau-dev on Ubuntu 18.04.6. Can you help me?

```
~$ sudo apt-get install libvdpau-dev 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. 
This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable the distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
libvdpau-dev : 
Depends: libvdpau1 (= 1.1.1-3ubuntu1) but 1.3-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.2 is to be installed 
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: You have to run ppa-purge for thirdparty PPA repository which provides vdpau and then resume package installation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had tried PPA repositories, but they are good only for old Ubuntu versions, like 12.04 - 16.04. I am searching for ubuntu 18.04. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy libvdpau-dev libvdpau1` to the question along with `grep -ir ^deb /etc/apt --include="*.list"`.

Comment: Thanks. I will try your advice and soon replay you.